# Looking for an open source PDF automation tool that works with Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, automation, software-testing

We are manually filling PDF forms and these forms have an inbuilt validation logic using JavaScript when we select the validation button. I am looking for a tool that can automate data entry into this PDF file and also select the validation button within this form. The PDF opens only in Adobe Acrobat so we cannot afford Acrobat PRO license for PDF automation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The whole point of form fields are they are for bulk use by Acrobat reader so you do not open the PDF you open the designers FDF with the FDF data and it loads the PDFgraphics around those field entries. HOWEVER you have Javascript in that PDF so that needs to be allowed to Autorun when the PDF runs and checks the already loaded data. So there are two methods I know  to use basic FDF but neither will expect to run exploitable sripting hence you are tied to having a human trigger a potential exploit (this is not needed when using Acrobat API)